# "Type hints" for Lua

Tags: lua

First of all, I apologize for using a term from another language, but it's the only one I know to describe what I need.

I have a C++ engine, and I 'inject' some 'classes' so that the script can create an instance of the engine and run, and this works very well.

However, I would like to know if there is a way to 'insert typing' into the Lua language server so that in my text editor, the types of the engine are recognized? (image)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that be a case for [definition files](https://luals.github.io/wiki/definition-files/) - assuming you are using LuaLS (which I guess since you wrote "Lua language server")

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77429985/type-hints-for-lua#comment136504913_77429985), using a [definition file](https://luals.github.io/wiki/definition-files/) seems the natural way to go.

The [Lua Language Server (LuaLS)](https://luals.github.io/) does support the use of definition files, which allow you to define libraries, APIs, or any external code that you want the language server to be aware of. That would in turn enables features like code completion and proper diagnostics within your text editor like VSCode.

To create a definition file, you would write a Lua file with annotations and a `---@meta` tag at the top. These annotations describe the structure and types of the classes or functions you are defining. Said [annotations](https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki/Annotations) are based on [EmmyLua annotations](https://emmylua.github.io/annotation.html), although there is a [rename in progress](https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/discussions/1587).

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/61925890/183302905-32daa693-1da6-4d62-a10c-40f018b1eb5b.png]

To make use of the definition files in VSCode, you would provide the path to these files in the `workspace.library` setting so that the Lua Language Server can reference them. There are many such definitions already available in the form of add-ons, which can be installed using the add-on manager in VSCode or found in repositories such as the LLS-Addons repo or LuaCATS organization.

---

In your case:

Annotate your Lua code with EmmyLua comments that specify the types of variables and function parameters/return values.

To adapt the LuaLS definition file example to the provided Lua code, you will create annotations for the `Enginefactory` and the methods used such as `new`, `set_title`, `set_width`, `set_height`, `create`, `prefetch`, `spawn`, and `on_update`. Below is an example of what the definition file might look like for the `Enginefactory` class and the `Engine` class it creates:

```lua
---@meta

---@class Enginefactory
Enginefactory = {}

---@return Engine
function Enginefactory.new() end

---@class Engine
local Engine = {}

---@param title string
---@return Engine
function Engine:set_title(title) end

---@param width number
---@return Engine
function Engine:set_width(width) end

---@param height number
---@return Engine
function Engine:set_height(height) end

---@return Engine
function Engine:create() end

---@param assets string[]
function Engine:prefetch(assets) end

---@return Entity
function Engine:spawn() end

---@class Entity
local Entity = {}

---@param pixmap string
function Entity:set_pixmap(pixmap) end

---@param updateFunc fun(self:Entity)
function Entity:on_update(updateFunc) end
```

You would place these annotations in a `.lua` file within your project, and then inform the Lua language server of its location through the `workspace.library` setting in VSCode. This will allow the language server to provide autocompletion and tooltips for the methods defined in the injected engine classes.

```
VSCode
  │
  │  └─── workspace.library
  │           │
  │           ▼
  │       Definition Files
  │       (Enginefactory.lua, Engine.lua)
  │           │
  │           ▼
  └───> Lua Language Server
            │
            │ Reads
            ▼
       EmmyLua Annotations
            │
            │ Injects
            ▼
       Text Editor Autocomplete & Hints
```